# PWA shows manifest.json after splash screen

Tags: json, angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm having a problem with a PWA I'm developing using Angular. After adding the app to the homescreen in a mobile device, I tried to open it from the home screen but instead of showing the menu, just after the splash screen it shows me my manifest.json file.

```
{
  "name": "Bitpoint",
  "short_name": "Bitpoint",
  "theme_color": "#03A9F4",
  "background_color": "#03A9F4",
  "display": "standalone",
  "Scope": "/",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "start_url": "#/app/recibirpago",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can check this error by yourself going to [my app](https://logindb-87a54.firebaseapp.com/#/auth/login) and adding the app to your homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

In `start_url` to need to set a path to the `index.html` file, for example:

`"start_url": "index.html/#/app/recibirpago",` or
`"start_url": "./#/app/recibirpago",`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I'm getting this error `Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')`

Answer (score 0):

I added / for starturl

```
start_url:"/"
```